# Aggregate AND count data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, aggregate

I have a data frame with N participants. Each participant has 50 trials, half of them with condition A and half with condition B. In each trial, they either got 0 or 1 in a certain variable. I need to count the occurrences of the 0's or 1's for each participant, in each of the conditions.

so far, i tried something like this:

the_answer = aggregate(certain_variable==0 ~ participant, data = data[data$condition=="A" , ], FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE).

The problem is I always get a different number of participants in my results, instead of getting the same N participants, with different counting of the variables...

Hope i was clear enough... I would really appreciate any help...

thanks!

Comment: Put the output of str(data) in your question body (properly formatted).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your description of your data was pretty clear, but not certain my solution matches what you wanted. Click the check mark if the answer solves the problem and otherwise let us know if there is some issue and we will try to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

## Generate example data

```r
###########################################################################
# Set-up
###########################################################################

# Packages
library(tibble)
libary(dplyr)

# Simulation parameters
set.seed(123)
participant_n <- 3
trial_n <- 50
trials_per_arm <- trial_n * 0.5
outcome_prob_A <- 0.8
outcome_prob_B <- 0.2

###########################################################################
# Simulate data
###########################################################################

# Participant and trials structure
data <- tibble(
  participant = rep(1:participant_n, trial_n),
  trial = rep(1:trial_n, each = participant_n),
)

# Randomly assign half of the trials to each condition, letting the trials
# assigned vary across participants
data <- data %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(
    condition = sample(rep(c("A", "B"), trials_per_arm),
                       trial_n,
                       replace = FALSE),
    outcome = case_when(
      condition == "A" ~ rbinom(n(), 1, outcome_prob_A),
      condition == "B" ~ rbinom(n(), 1, outcome_prob_B)
    )
  )


#> # A tibble: 150 x 4
#> # Groups:   participant [3]
#>    participant trial condition outcome
#>          <int> <int> <chr>       <int>
#>  1           1     1 A               1
#>  2           2     1 A               1
#>  3           3     1 B               0
#>  4           1     2 A               1
#>  5           2     2 B               0
#>  6           3     2 B               1
#>  7           1     3 B               1
#>  8           2     3 A               1
#>  9           3     3 B               0
#> 10           1     4 A               1
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

## Count each outcome for each participant

```r
data %>%
  group_by(participant, condition, outcome) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    participant condition outcome     n
#>          <int> <chr>       <int> <int>
#>  1           1 A               0     2
#>  2           1 A               1    23
#>  3           1 B               0    21
#>  4           1 B               1     4
#>  5           2 A               0     5
#>  6           2 A               1    20
#>  7           2 B               0    22
#>  8           2 B               1     3
#>  9           3 A               0     4
#> 10           3 A               1    21
#> 11           3 B               0    22
#> 12           3 B               1     3

# If you just want counts for each outcome for each condition:
data %>%
  group_by(condition, outcome) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   condition outcome     n
#>   <chr>       <int> <int>
#> 1 A               0    11
#> 2 A               1    64
#> 3 B               0    65
#> 4 B               1    10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I"m still struggling with it because in eventually need a column with all the N's of each participant's outcomes by conditions..

Comment: You will need to revise your question to be more precise in that case,